# Why does `scipy.interpolate.griddata` fail for readonly arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have some data which I try to interpolate using `scipy.interpolate.griddata`. In my use-case I marked some of the numpy arrays read-only, which apparently breaks the interpolation:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x0 = 10 * np.random.randn(100, 2)
y0 = np.random.randn(100)
x1 = np.random.randn(3, 2)

x0.flags.writeable = False
# x1.flags.writeable = False

interpolate.griddata(x0, y0, x1)
```

yields the following exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-a6e09dbdd371> in <module>()
      6 # x1.flags.writeable = False
      7 
----> 8 interpolate.griddata(x0, y0, x1)

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.pyc in griddata(points, values, xi, method, fill_value, rescale)
    216         ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,
    217                                   rescale=rescale)
--> 218         return ip(xi)
    219     elif method == 'cubic' and ndim == 2:
    220         ip = CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,

scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.NDInterpolatorBase.__call__ (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:3930)()

scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator._evaluate_double (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:5267)()

scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.LinearNDInterpolator._do_evaluate (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:6006)()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.so in View.MemoryView.memoryview_cwrapper (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:17829)()

/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.so in View.MemoryView.memoryview.__cinit__ (scipy/interpolate/interpnd.c:14104)()

ValueError: buffer source array is read-only
```

Clearly, the interpolation function doesn't like that the arrays are write-protected. However, I don't understand why they want to change this – I certainly don't expect my input to be mutated by a call to the interpolation function and this is also not mentioned in the documentation as far as I can tell. Why would the function behave like this?

Note that setting `x1` readonly instead of `x0` leads to a similar error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [relevant code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/interpnd.pyx) is written in Cython, and when Cython requests a memoryview of the input array, [it always asks for a writeable one](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/cython-devel/2013-February/003396.html), even if you don't need it.

Since an array flagged as non-writeable will refuse to provide a writeable memoryview, the code fails, even though it didn't need to write to the array in the first place.

Comment: I see – this explains the error, but I still think it is a bug in scipy to not make a copy itself but throw an error. Ultimately, cython should probably be changed to allow read-only memory views. I opened a bug report for scipy  (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6864). Let's see what the guys say other there